# Installing singularity-container in version 3.3 from a repository

Tags: 18.04, apt, repository, container, unsupported-packages

On ubuntu 18.04 I'm looking to install via `apt` the container software [Singularity](https://sylabs.io/singularity/) in version 3.3 or above. 
However ubuntu's default repo `universe` offers Singularity (as the package `singularity-container`) only in version version 2.4.

Is there another repo for ubuntu 18.04 LTS I can add which installs Singularity version 3.3 or higher?

Comment: You can always just compile from sources. It's relatively easy and well explained on the official Sylab website. Ask a follow question if you hit errors!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but my solution:

Install Centos 7 instead if ubuntu 18.04. This has Singularity 3.5.3 on the EPEL repository available.